# Reached Limit using Google Geocoding Web Service

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

We have a page that accepts a city, state combination or a zip code.  Upon submit, it passes that information to the Geocode Webservice for Google Maps and returns a list of store location results based on the information passed.  We sporadically have issues with bots hitting that page multiple times and then Google shuts down our usage of the geocode webservice for the day.  Is there a way to ask Google to restore this more quickly?  How should we handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [client-side geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), the limits there will be based on the client not the server.

[Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat)

Answer (score 0):

As specified on in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits), "Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 requests per day (User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up to 100,000 requests per day.)"

There's a nice article on [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) which discusses caching and other options to optimize geocoding. The "Quota Considerations" section should be useful.

Remember to use client-side geocoding if at all possible, so that the quota limit will be counted per client, instead of per service/server. If you're still hitting the limits, you might need to go for the Business version and pay for a larger limit.